# Date and Time in Access Database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have one field named "Date_Capture" created on the access form which is available for end user to select the date by using date picker. When user is selecting the date using date picker then only date is coming correct but the correct time is not showing up. for each record time is coming like 11/10/2015 12:00:00 AM, 11//11/2016 12:00:00 AM.I need to show the exact time when we select a particular date using date picker.

is there any work around to fix this? Please let me know.

Thanks,
RR

Comment: There's no fix to this because the date picker is only a DATE picker and you can't get TIME from it. You need to manage it yourself by code.

Comment: I think your question is unclear. Do you wish the user to select Now(), or a date and time chosen by them?

Comment: @Thomas, could you please give some example?

Comment: @Fionnuala : i want them to current current date and time using time picker. when i am using Date/Time, Date Picker is coming automatically for the user

Comment: Just set the default value to Now() which is current date and time.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually faster just to type the time, for example as described here:

[Entering 24-hour time with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23539/Entering-24-hour-time-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

with full code also here at [GitHub](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.TimeEntry.git).

You can enter dates much the same way:

[Entering ISO formatted date with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/24659/Entering-ISO-formatted-date-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

and code is here at [GitHub](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.DateEntry.git).

Code:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Form_LogonDate"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = True
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

    Dim DefaultDate         As Date
    Dim DefaultFormat       As String
    Dim DefaultInputMask    As String

Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)

    Dim ctl                 As Control

    Dim SelStart            As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    Set ctl = Screen.ActiveControl

    Select Case ctl.Name
        Case "Logon"
            SelStart = ctl.SelStart
            ' Clear deleted digits by resetting the input mask.
            ctl.InputMask = DefaultInputMask
            ctl.SelStart = SelStart
            ctl.SelLength = 1
            Response = acDataErrContinue
    End Select

    Set ctl = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim InitialDate         As Date

    ' Set initial date.
    InitialDate = Date

    ' Format and length of DefaultFormat and
    ' first part of DefaultInputMask must match.
    DefaultFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
    DefaultInputMask = "0000/00/00;1;0"

    Me!Logon.Format = DefaultFormat
    Me!Logon.InputMask = DefaultInputMask
    Me!Logon.ShowDatePicker = False
    SetDefaultDate InitialDate

End Sub

Private Sub Logon_AfterUpdate()

    With Me!Logon
        If IsNull(.Value) Then
            ' Rem this line out to allow the textbox to be cleared.
            .Value = DefaultDate
        ElseIf .Value < DateSerial(9999, 12, 31) Then
            SetDefaultDate DateAdd("d", 1, .Value)
        Else
            SetDefaultDate .Value
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Logon_Click()

    Dim SelStart            As Integer

    With Me!Logon
        If .SelStart = 4 Or .SelStart = 7 Then
            ' Move the cursor off the separator (slash)
            ' to the first digit of months or days.
            .SelStart = .SelStart + 1
        End If
        SelStart = .SelStart
        .SelStart = SelStart
        .SelLength = 1
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Logon_Enter()

    With Me!Logon
        If IsNull(.Value) Then
            .Value = DefaultDate
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Logon_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)

    Dim Text                As String
    Dim Length              As Integer
    Dim SelStart            As Integer

    With Me!Logon
        Select Case KeyAscii
            Case vbKeyBack, vbKeyTab, Asc(vbLf), vbKeyReturn, vbKeyEscape, vbKeyF16
                ' Allow navigation etc. with
                ' BackSpace, Tab, Ctrl+Enter, Enter, Escape, Ctrl+BackSpace
            Case Is > 0
                Text = .Text
                Length = Len(Text)
                SelStart = .SelStart

                If KeyAscii < vbKey0 Or KeyAscii > vbKey9 Then
                    ' Replace any invalid entry with a zero.
                    KeyAscii = vbKey0
                End If

                If SelStart < Length Then
                    Select Case SelStart

                        ' Year part.
                        Case Is = 0
                            ' First digit of year.
                            If KeyAscii = vbKey0 Then
                                ' No year before 1000.
                                KeyAscii = vbKey1
                            End If

                        ' Month part.
                        Case Is = 5
                            ' First digit of month.
                            If KeyAscii > vbKey1 Then
                                ' No month with tens beyond 1.
                                KeyAscii = vbKey1
                            End If
                        Case Is = 6
                            ' Second digit of month.
                            Select Case Val(Mid(.Text, 6, 1))
                                Case Is = 0
                                    ' Month is < 10.
                                    If KeyAscii = vbKey0 Then
                                        ' Month cannot be 00.
                                        KeyAscii = vbKey1
                                    End If
                                Case Is > 0
                                    ' Month is 10+.
                                    If KeyAscii > vbKey2 Then
                                        ' No month beyond 12.
                                        KeyAscii = vbKey2
                                    End If
                            End Select

                        ' Day part.
                        Case Is = 8
                            ' First digit of day.
                            Select Case Val(Mid(.Text, 6, 2))
                                Case Is = 2
                                    ' Month is February.
                                    If KeyAscii > vbKey2 Then
                                        ' No day with tens beyond 2 for February.
                                        KeyAscii = vbKey2
                                    End If
                                Case Else
                                    If KeyAscii > vbKey3 Then
                                        ' No day with tens beyond 3.
                                        KeyAscii = vbKey3
                                    End If
                            End Select
                        Case Is = 9
                            ' Second digit of day.
                            Select Case Mid(.Text, 9, 1)
                                Case Is = 3
                                    ' Days of 30.
                                    Select Case Val(Mid(.Text, 6, 2))
                                        Case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
                                            If KeyAscii > vbKey1 Then
                                                ' No day beyond 31.
                                                KeyAscii = vbKey1
                                            End If
                                        Case 4, 6, 9, 11
                                            If KeyAscii > vbKey0 Then
                                                ' No day beyond 30.
                                                KeyAscii = vbKey0
                                            End If
                                    End Select
                                Case Is = 2
                                    ' Days of 20.
                                    Select Case Val(Mid(.Text, 6, 2))
                                        Case 2
                                            If KeyAscii = vbKey9 Then
                                                ' Check for leap year.
                                                If Month(DateAdd("d", 1, DateSerial(Val(Mid(.Text, 1, 4)), 2, 28))) = 3 Then
                                                    ' Not a leap year.
                                                    KeyAscii = vbKey8
                                                End If
                                            End If
                                    End Select
                                Case Is = 0
                                    ' Days of 00.
                                    If KeyAscii = vbKey0 Then
                                        ' No day of 00.
                                        KeyAscii = vbKey1
                                    End If
                            End Select

                    End Select
                End If

        End Select
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub SetDefaultDate(ThisDate As Date)

    DefaultDate = ThisDate
    Me!Logon.DefaultValue = Format(ThisDate, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#")

End Sub
```

and:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Form_Logon"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = True
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

    Dim DefaultTime     As Date

Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)

    Const TimeHourMaximum   As Integer = 24
    Const TimeHourDefault   As Integer = 20
    Const TimeMinuteTenMax  As Integer = 5

    Dim ctl                 As Control

    Dim Text                As String
    Dim SelStart            As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    Set ctl = Screen.ActiveControl

    Select Case ctl.Name
        Case "Logon"
            Text = ctl.Text
            SelStart = ctl.SelStart
            If Not IsDate(Text) Then
                DoCmd.Beep
                If Val(Left(Text, 2)) > TimeHourMaximum Then
                    Mid(Text, 1) = CStr(TimeHourDefault)
                ElseIf Len(Text) > 3 Then
                    ' Length of Text is larger than two hour digits and the kolon.
                    Mid(Text, 1 + 3) = CStr(TimeMinuteTenMax)
                End If
            End If
            ctl.Text = Text
            ctl.SelStart = SelStart
            ctl.SelLength = 1
            Response = acDataErrContinue
    End Select

    Set ctl = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Const InitialTime   As Date = #6:00:00 AM#

    Me!Logon.ShowDatePicker = False
    Me!Logon.InputMask = "90:00;1;0"
    Me!Logon.Format = "hh:nn"
    SetDefaultTime InitialTime

End Sub

Private Sub Logon_AfterUpdate()

    With Me!Logon
        If IsNull(.Value) Then
            ' Rem this line out to allow the textbox to be cleared.
            .Value = #12:00:00 AM#
        Else
            SetDefaultTime DateAdd("n", 1, .Value)
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Logon_Click()

    With Me!Logon
        If .SelStart = 2 Then
            ' Move the cursor off the separator (colon)
            ' to the first digit of minutes.
            .SelStart = 3
            .SelLength = 1
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Logon_Enter()

    With Me!Logon
        If IsNull(.Value) Then
            .Value = DefaultTime
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Logon_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)

    Dim Text        As String
    Dim Char        As String
    Dim Length      As Integer
    Dim SelStart    As Integer

    With Me!Logon
        Select Case KeyAscii
            Case vbKeyBack, vbKeyTab, Asc(vbLf), vbKeyReturn, vbKeyEscape, vbKeyF16
                ' Allow navigation etc. with
                ' BackSpace, Tab, Ctrl+Enter, Enter, Escape, Ctrl+BackSpace
            Case Is > 0
                Text = .Text
                Length = Len(Text)
                SelStart = .SelStart

                If KeyAscii < vbKey0 Or KeyAscii > vbKey9 Then
                    ' Replace any invalid entry with a zero.
                    KeyAscii = vbKey0
                End If

                Char = Mid(Text, 1 + SelStart, 1)
                If SelStart < Length Then
                    If KeyAscii <= vbKey0 + 2 Then
                        ' Always accept 0, 1, 2.
                    Else
                        ' Check if the text will represent a valid time.
                        ' If not, restore the overwritten digit.
                        Mid(Text, 1 + SelStart, 1) = Chr(KeyAscii)
                        If Not IsDate(Text) Then
                            DoCmd.Beep
                            KeyAscii = Asc(Char)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
        End Select
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub SetDefaultTime(ThisTime As Date)

    DefaultTime = ThisTime
    Me!Logon.DefaultValue = Format(ThisTime, "\#hh:nn:00 AM/PM\#")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to Thomas G and RRO, put this code into the Code Builder for one of the Date fields, After Update Function.

```
Dim X As String

X = Format (Now(), "hh:mm:ss")

Me!YourFieldName.Value = X
```